# Ngx scrollbar not loading content

Tags: html, node.js, sass, angular13

I have added ngx scrollbar to my project and it is working fine but when somebody clone the project and run npm install ngx scrollbar not loading any content and no errors also. Can somebody help with this . I am using angualr 13 and node 16 and ngx scrollbar 7.3.0